# Select a dynamic Range in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell, selection

I need to select and delete different ranges that is produced inside a loop. Everytime it changes size and location!

```
Sub DelDoublicate()

' some selection of a bigger range happens here. whole data that some parts of it needs to be deleted based on a simple algorithm:

Dim N As Integer
Dim inn As String
Dim out As String

For i = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
 If Range("D" & 12 + i) = Range("D" & 13 + i) Then
  N = N + 1
 ElseIf N > 1 Then
  inn = "F" & 12 + i - N
  out = "I" & 12 + i

'Here I need to select a range like Range("inn,out"), like Range(F14:I17)

Selection.Delete
N = 0
  End If
Next

End Sub
```

I tried many pattern to formulate a range. But I didn't succeeded. It's my first try in Excell VBA and it helps me save a lot of time at work.

Comment: You can use `Range(inn & ":" & out)`. But there are some issues to take care of: If your selection has  more than 12 rows the range to be deleted is part of the selection itself. It would be better to use a `Union` range where to place all the ranges (built as I suggested) and delete all of them (the `Union` range) at once, after the iteration. It would be better, I think, to show us what you **really** try accomplishing. One picture showing existing and another one showing what you need.

Comment: Thank You, Range(inn & ":" & out) solved the problem. I'm gonna look at Union method.... I'll come back.

Comment: @FaneDuru Hi, I was wrong about using "delete". I need to use "Clear" instead. Do I still have problem for more that 10 rows?